# CakePHP: can't access the Session when making AJAX call

Tags: ajax, session, cakephp

This question is for CakePHP 4.3:

In my action, I am accessing the session. For a normal GET request, everything works fine. If I call the same action through an AJAX request, I do not have access to the session. Why is that?

For example, even this does not work:

```
public function select3() {
  debug($this->request->getSession()->read());
}
```

For a GET request, the session is printed. For an AJAX call, an empty array is printed.

Is the AppController NOT called for an AJAX request?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check your browser's network console whether the session cookie is being sent alongside your AJAX request, and whether it has the correct session ID value, eg the same as the one that you receive in the previous non-AJAX request. Also check your error logs to make sure there's no errors like the session not being able to start because output has already been generated. Speaking of output, use logging instead of debug output when debugging session/header related stuff, otherwise you're just introducing more potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to "ndm" for your offered help.

I solved it after seeing that something was mixed up with the URLS.
The URL has "server-4.2" in it, and "server" is a link to it.
Both "server-4.2" and "server" seemed to have confused the Authentication controller.
Glad it works now.